# Getting all columns name in an table using trigger function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

How can I get all column names and their values in trigger function because i need to validate all column values before inserting into the table.I have tried below code.If we know that column name means we can get the value easily by using `NEW` object in trigger function as `NEW.myColumnName`.But here I need to get the column name dynamically...

```
    CREATE FUNCTION insert_update_validate() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..(TG_ARGV-1) LOOP
         IF TG_ARGV[i] IS NULL THEN                 
               RAISE EXCEPTION 'cannot have null VALUE', NEW.TG_ARGV[i];
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) is part of PostgreSQL, casting a row to hstore is the primary method to iterate on its columns, at least in a plpgsql context. Otherwise as a language it doesn't provide any construct to extract column names from rows.

Basically it's about iterating over `each(store(NEW))`. Here's a skeleton you may use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_update_validate() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
 k text;
 v text;
BEGIN
  FOR k,v IN select key,value from each(hstore(NEW)) LOOP
    if v is null then
      raise exception 'value is null for column %', k;
    end if;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```